# How can I use array_shift + implode?

Tags: php, arrays, implode

I have a little problem. I have eshop and in detail of product I need to have table with parameters values.

```
 if(!empty($data['params']) && is_array($data['params']))
{
    $c .= '<dl>';
        $p = 0;
        foreach($data['params'] as $param_id => $param)
        {
            if(!empty($param['values']) && is_array($param['values']))
            {
                $p++;
                $c .= '<dt>'.$param['name'].':</dt>';
                $c .= '<dd>';
                    $value = array_shift($param['values']);
                    $c .= $value;
                $c .= '</dd>';
            }
            if($p == 5)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    $c .= '</dl>';
}
```

Problem is, that array_shift give me back only first value of every parameter and I need all of them, if there are. How can I use "implode" function to echo all values?

Comment: Could you please print_r the $data and paste the output here along with your expected result

Comment: I should, but it is a lot of informations - one product in eshop - parametrs, informations, ingredients etc.I have tip from my friend, that there is solution to implode other values to $value, but now he is on holiday, so I cant discuss it with him. I didn't help you, right?:D